# Calculating Prime Numbers (Novice)

Tags: java, loops, primes

This program checks if a user's input number is prime.

My problem is in the `if` statement. For some reason the `Boolean` is never switched. If the number is prime, it will just give both results.

What am I missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prime 
{

     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is prime:");
       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n = kb.nextInt();
       boolean more = true;

       do
       {
           for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
           {
               if (n <=1 || n%i==0) 
               {
                    System.out.println(n + " is not prime");
                    more = false;
               }              
            } 
       }
       while (more);
       System.out.println(n + " is prime");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is switched, or you would have an infinite loop. Hint: What stops your program from printing the final `System.out.println`?

Comment: I somehow don't understand what the while loop is for.

Comment: i'm not sure. this is where i am stuck! should I add a break?

Comment: nevermind. i got rid the the while loop entirely. it works now. thanks boris. the code is edited to proper function

Answer (score 2):

Remove the print which is inside `if()` and use the below code after the do while loop

```
if(more)
 System.out.println(n + " is prime");
else
 System.out.println(n + " is not prime");
```

and also you dont need a do while loop  remove it.Complete Code

```
 System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is prime:");
 Scanner kb = new Scanner(System. in );
 int n = kb.nextInt();
 boolean more = true;


 for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
    if (n <= 1 || n % i == 0) {

        more = false;
        break;
    }
 }
 if (more) System.out.println(n + " is prime");
 else System.out.println(n + " is not prime");
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/1HuhNH)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to check prime numbers with few lines using a `for` loop. It's better for performance.

**Code to check prime numbers:**

```
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < n && isPrime; i++) {
        isPrime = !(n % i == 0);
    }
```

**Full class according to your example:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is prime:");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = kb.nextInt();

        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < n && isPrime; i++) {
            isPrime = !(n % i == 0);
        }

        System.out.println(n + " is prime - " + isPrime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is prime:");
           Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
           int n = kb.nextInt();
           boolean prime = true;

               for (int i = 2; i <n; i++)
               {
                   if (n <=1 || n%i==0) 
                   {
                        prime = false;
                        break;
                   }
                }
               if(prime)
               {
                   System.out.println(n + " is prime");
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("Not prime");
               }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following logic is working. Please try this.

```
int count=0; 
for(i=2;i<=n/2;++i)
{
  if(n%i==0)
  {
      count=1;
      break;
  }
}
if (count==0)
  System.out.println(i+" is a prime number.");
else
  System.out.println(i+" is not a prime number.");
```

If the count got increased, the given number is divisible by some other numbers. Or else It should be a prime number.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check all the way up to n, just up to the square root. which if you calculate before should make your loop take less iterations and be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with simple `for` loop.

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is prime:");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = kb.nextInt();
boolean isPrime = true;

if (n < 1)
    isPrime = false;
else
    for(int i = 2; 2 * i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }  
    }

System.out.println( n + " is " + (isPrime? "" : "not ") + "prime");
```